# Setting multiple objects per each cycle in a for loop

Tags: javascript, object, variables

I need to create multiple objects where I have one array of keys to go to multiple different sets of values. I have gotten to the point where I can set the keys to the correct data, but I don't know how to assign each set of key/value pairs to an object. I would need something like object(i) for each object created

function toJSON() {

```
let temp = {};
let temp2 = [];
let temp3 = [];
for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

    for (let j = 0; j < key.length; j++) {
        temp = {
            [key[j]]: values[i][j],
        }
        temp2.push(temp)

    }
    //Then take this info and put it into an object
}


console.log(temp2)
```

}

Comment: I think Object.values(), Object.keys(), Object.entries() will be handy to you.

Comment: To assign porperties to an object: obj[property] = value;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assign some arbitrary data to `keys` and `values` so you can verify that I've understood the question:

```js
const keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const values = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

const result = values.map(value => Object.assign({}, ...keys.map((key, i) =>
   ({[key]: value[i]}))))
   
console.log(result)
```

Is that the output you were looking for?

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, time to learn the map function, thanks!